# Magento - rwd fallback not working for new theme

Tags: xml, templates, magento, magento-1.9, skin

I've extensively followed several seperate guides for creating a child theme that falls back to rwd in magento. Each time i do it however, i end up getting stuck like this.

[Homepage Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXoLb.png)

**The steps i followed:**

Made new directory /app/design/frontend/mypackage/mytheme which contains etc, layout and template. Layout contains local.xml (which is blank for now) and etc contains theme.xml.

```
<theme>
    <parent>rwd/default</parent>
</theme>
```

Made new directory /skin/frontend/mypackage/mytheme with contains a copy of the images, css and scss from rwd. There's also a js folder in here. 
In the scss folder, i've modified config.rb to have the following:

```
http_path = "/skin/frontend/mypackage/mytheme/"
css_dir = "../css"
sass_dir = "../scss"
images_dir = "../images"
javascripts_dir = "../js"
relative_assets = true
add_import_path "../../../rwd/default/scss"
output_style = :expanded
environment = :production
```

According to all the documentation i've gone over this should be the bare minimum for a fallback scenario and as i've got no other xml files set up it should, in theory, look exactly like the rwd theme?

Am i going about this the right way?

The backend is set to mypackage and the theme is set to mytheme. It's been a while since i've worked with magento but i can't see what's wrong.

Comment: Is your magento store a multi store setup, i would check that the website and store view settings in the design section of system configuration. Also can you confirm you have completely flushed the cache?

Comment: I've turned the cache off for development as it's a pain in the neck with it on having to flush every change. Even so, i've took the liberty of clearing out the folder anyway with any changes. Theres not a multi store setup.

Comment: According to the inspector between the two i'm missing a css file called "madisonisland.css". This is the only difference between the two. But according to what i've read theres no reason to reference this at all...

Comment: when you view source can you see any reference in your file paths to rwd?

Comment: There are no references to rwd in my source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After smashing my head against a wall for a while i realised that i was calling a template from another package. I've made "mytheme" inside the rwd folder and everything lines up properly. Thank you Cameron for helping me!